# How to attach a document from a SharePoint library into a list item?

Tags: list, document-library, sharepoint-calendar, attachments

My client wants to attach a 'Minutes' document (in a SharePoint document library) to a meeting event (SharePoint list item).  The trouble they have is that the OOTB 'Attach File' browse option opens 'Windows Explorer' and points to documents stored on their PC, rather than within SharePoint.  Is it possible to make the 'Attach File' function point at a specific SharePoint document library (or path)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SharePoint Column type "Publishing Hyperlink" and  you can directly provide provision to user to upload attachments from SharePoint Itself.

Publishing must be enabled by a site collection administrator for these column types to appear. To enable publishing, go to Settings Small Settings gear that took the place of Site Settings.> Site Settings. Under Site Collection Administration, click Site collection features. Scroll down to SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure and click Activate.

For Further Reference:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-publishing-columns-to-content-types-lists-or-libraries-4e268d2e-4822-4bc6-a992-88287119a052

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have just done a test on my test site and this column would resolve the issue.  I'll now look at how the 'Server Publishing Infrastructure' feature will affect my clients site when activated.

Comment: If it has resolved your issue. Please mark it as Answer, so that Question is closed.

Comment: I've deployed this to my clients environment and it's exactly what they required. Thanks.